# Code size with const objects

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, extern

I have a few source files in which some `const` variables are required.
In the provided framework there is a .hpp header file that includes definitions (not only declarations) of those variables and this header is included in my source files mentioned before.
Then I realized, that each of my source files contains a copy of that RO data `const` variable, so in order to reduce memory footprint (I am working on ebdedded systems) I made one more .hpp that is included in my source files and which contains `extern` references to those variables (included somewhere else).
I compared build .o object information and saw that code size and RO data sizes are larger when using .hpp with extern references rather than with actual variables' definitions.
Why is that?

**UPDATE:**
I have made the mistake. To be specific here is a fragment of linker map file:
(note: RW, ZI removed)
Not using externs:
Code: 1192
(inc. data): 84
RO Data: 144

Using externs:
Code: 1392
(inc. data): 216
RO Data: 144

But my mistake has more new questions than answers:

1. In this case, why RO (const data) size didn't change?
2. What is inc. data in this scope?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this completely without knowing the specifics of compiler and platform.

Comment: This is neither an ARM nor embedded specific question - you might want to drop this tags.

Comment: @molbdnilo : The behaviour can be completely explained by the semantics of C++.  It is not compiler nor platform specific.

Comment: Now I see, you're expecting `const` = "read-only segment". That's not the case. Added a little bit to my answer.

Comment: "Then I realized, that each of my source files contains a copy of that RO data"  This seems to be the root of the problem. Why would there be copies? The overall program design might be the true culprit here.

Answer (score 4):

When the definitions were not `extern` the compiler could inline them, so they are stored directly in the code, in a "load immediate" instruction.
(This is known as "constant-folding".)

Making them `extern` hid the defintions from the compiler, forcing it to store the values during compilation and generate code to fetch them at runtime.

They are not stored in a read-only segment because they need to be initialised when the program starts, and thus must be writable.
A read-only segment is only good for things that never change, such as the contents of string literals.

Comment: Yap, I also think that this cause increased code sized. But what about RO  data (const data)?

Comment: If a value is `const`, the compiler can usually easily put the value inline as part of the code. If this happens for all the times that the constant is used, it never needs its own memory location. If the same constant is marked as `extern`, then the compiler doesn't know the value and is forced to read the value at runtime - and store that value somewhere in memory.

Comment: I did not included both headers. In either test case there was only one of them: with definitions OR with external references.

Comment: Without extern, sometimes the actual constant will not even be needed. The compiler resorts to other tricks that will have the same end-result as if the constant was used.

Comment: @SvenNilsson I'm not sure how that would be contradicting my answer. Should I clarify what I mean with "inline"?

Comment: It does not contradict your answer, it _confirms_ your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Constants of basic types and without external linkage in C++ have no storage or address *unless* one takes its address.  Instead the literal value is inserted into the code as if you have typed its numeric value.  For example the code:

```
const NUM = 25 ;
int n1 = NUM ;
int n2 = NUM ;
```

will generate identical code to:

```
int n1 - 25 ;
int n2 = 25 ;
```

that is because it takes fewer instructions to insert a literal value that it does to copy that value from read-only memory.

If however you had code:

```
const NUM = 25 ;
int* np = &NUM ;
```

then `NUM` would be forced to have storage.

When you declare a const as external, then you are saying that the value exists elsewhere, and that the linker will allocate it.  The compiler cannot know the value that it will have if it is defined in a separate module, and it cannot know whether some other module will take its address, so it must be explicitly stored - which makes both the read-only data space larger but also the code space.

While in C++ const variables outside of a function or class scope have implicit static linkage, in C they are implicitly `extern`.  So you may find that if you use C compilation the results differ.  For interoperability, if you declare a const in a header file it is perhaps wise to explicitly declare it `static` in order to ensure the same semantics in both languages.

Comment: @artlessnoise : fixed.  Thanks.